# A problem on chain rule

Tags: complex-analysis, chain-rule

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic function and $u:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ subharmonic function. Prove that $\Delta(u\circ f)=((\Delta u)\circ f)|f'|^2$.

Suppose $f=g+ih$. Then $f'=g_x+ih_x$. So $|f'|^2=g_x^2+h_x^2$. Moreover, since $f$ is holomorphic, $g,h$ are harmonic. So, $g_{xx}+g_{yy}=0$ and $h_{xx}+h_{yy}=0$.

$\Delta u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}$, So $(\Delta u)\circ f=u_{xx}(f)+u_{yy}(f)$. Hence, $((\Delta u)\circ f)|f'|^2=(u_{xx}(f)+u_{yy}(f))(g_x^2+h_x^2)$.

By chain rule $\Delta(u\circ f)=(u_x\circ f)f_{xx}+(u_{xx}\circ f)f_x^2+(u_y\circ f)f_{yy}+(u_{yy}\circ f)f_y^2$.

Now my questions are:

1. Is the last expression correct?
2. How do I expand $f_x$ and $f_{xx}$ by chain rule?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are asking how you get rid of the $f_{xx}$ term ?
Actually, I think it is better to use real notation and write $f(x,y)=(a(x,y),b(x,y))$. Then $\partial_x a= \partial_y b$ and $\partial_y a=-\partial_x b$ (Cauchy-Riemann).

For example, $\partial_x (u\circ f) = \partial_x [u(a(x,y),b(x,y))] = (\partial_x u) \circ f \; \partial_x a + (\partial_y u)\circ f \; \partial_x b$ and then 
\begin{align}
   \partial_{xx}(u\circ f) & = \partial_{xx} [u(a(x,y),b(x,y))] =
\\
   &  (\partial_{xx} u) \circ f \ \  (\partial_x a)^2 + 2(\partial_{xy} u)\circ f  \ \  \partial_x a \; \partial_x b  + (\partial_{yy} u)\circ f \ \  (\partial_x b)^2 \\
 & (\partial_x u) \circ f \ \partial_{xx}a + (\partial_y u) \circ f \ \partial_{xx}b .
\end{align}

Do the same for the $\partial_{yy}$ derivative and 
 use Cauchy-Riemann. The mixed derivative vanishes and the rest combines to the claimed result.

Comment: Ok then I can consider $f$ as $f(x,y)=(g(x,y), h(x,y))$. But how do I get rid of terms like $f_x,f_{xx}$? Can you please explain from where I can start to do so?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the way you get $\partial_{xx}$?

Comment: The notation is a bit confusing. I have tried to clarify. The essential part is that when you differentiate a term like  $(\partial_x u)\circ f = (\partial_x u) (a(x,y),b(x,y))$ wrt $x$ you get two terms as you should derive through $a$ and through $b$. Does this help?

Comment: Ya that's true. But I got an expression for $u_{xx}$ with the same terms as yours plus some additional terms. But when I do the same for $u_{yy}$ and add them together I got the required final answer. So i am little confused.

Comment: I apologize. I finally got your point and have added the missing terms. Probably the ones you had found as well (and which will disappear later on by Cauchy-Riemann). Hope there are no more mistakes.